# The jquery code works on console but not in script tags or in attached js file

Tags: jquery, click

```
$(".filter-close").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();

});
```

this snippet works in console but neither in script tags nor in attached js file.

Comment: Please at least copy+paste the code for the page your using it on, and click F12 to see if any error in dev console.

Comment: What error are you getting when run in script tag or attached js file?

Comment: Silly me but why this question get two upvotes???

Comment: @A.Wolff - i feel same way, till you realise how many people have same question because they fail to follow tutorial or similar and just copy paste code without testing. I do however wish that OP would actually state why the accepted answer worked for him, whether it was in fact a conflict.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wait for the DOM to be ready when calling your event handler:

```
jQuery(function($) { // this does the trick and also makes sure jQuery is not conflicting with another library 
    $(".filter-close").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

> <sup>When using another JavaScript library, we may wish to call $.noConflict() to avoid namespace difficulties. When this function is called, the $ shortcut is no longer available, forcing us to write jQuery each time we would normally write $. **However, the handler passed to the .ready() method can take an argument, which is passed the global jQuery object. This means we can rename the object within the context of our .ready() handler without affecting other code**</sup>

<sup>[Documentation for `.ready()` method](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)</sup>

Comment: Because OP said code works in console, we can assume `$` is already referring to jQuery but that's still good info

Comment: @A.Wolff: Sure, I just wanted to point out something the other answers haven't mentionned :)

Answer (score 2):

It may be an issue of not being present in the DOM when the event handler is attached.

Try something like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.

    $(".filter-close").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();

    });

});
```

The $.ready() (link below) ensures that it doesnt try to call the code to add the handler before the DOM is rendered, similar to OnLoad.

<sup>[Documentation for JQuery `.ready()` method](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)</sup>

There are also potential library conflicts (see @D4V1D answer for example of that), but we cant say for sure without knowing what error message is appearing in the console (if any) and ideally more about the surrounding code.

Please hit F12 and see what being printed in the console and/or network panel, or google "BrowserName dev console" if F12 does nothing.

But, as said it works in console, so i assume you mean dev console and that it is in fact just a timing issue, so unlikely a conflict (though still maybe syntax error somewhere else on page)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the element with `filter-close` class does not exist in the DOM at the time you call this function. I suppose you are adding elements to DOM dynamically. Are you?

Comment: This is not an answer, it's merely a comment.

Comment: @UjwalRatra - it may be both, but SO guidlines clear that an answer must answer the question, if you included code example of what to do if it Was dynamically added, then maybe its an answer - else its a comment only